# slideDown outside of table row on hover

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("jquery", "1");
</script>
</head>

<body>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>Column 1</td>
<td>Column x</td>
<td>
<div class="avail">Available Options</div>
<ul class="menu">
<li><a href="A.htm">Menu A</a></li>
<li><a href="B.htm">Menu B</a></li>
<li><a href="C.htm">Menu C</a></li>
</ul>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Column 1</td>
<td>Column x</td>
<td>
<div class="avail">Available Options</div>
<ul class="menu">
<li><a href="A.htm">Menu A</a></li>
<li><a href="C.htm">Menu C</a></li>
<li><a href="D.htm">Menu D</a></li>
</ul>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<script>
$('.menu').hide();
$('.avail').hover(function() {
    $(this).next().slideDown('slow')
    ,
    $(this).next().slideUp('slow');
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What I would like is for the menus to slide down over top of the rows that are beneath them.
Think of a window shade being drawn over top of row 2 if they hover over row 1.

Right now it's expanding the table row itself.
Maybe I should put columns 1-x in divs that are float left.
Probably need to use hoverIntent, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to pull this off with just some css.

```
.menu{
    position:absolute;
    background-color:white;
}
```

Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/5Ga7A/).